# Write deflated byte[] into zip file

Tags: java, zip, deflate

my data is stored deflated in a database.
You can donwload this data inflated as .txt via app.
Now it should be possible to download the data as .zip

I'm looking for a solution without decompressing the data and compressing it again via

```
// byte[] deflated = ...;
// File zipFile = ...;
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos))
{
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("data.txt");
    zos.putNextEntry(entry);
    zos.write(inflate(deflated));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handling
}
```

I tried to work with `entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED)` but it didn't work.
Google search only delivers solutions with uncompressed data.
Any idea?
GZip or 7z may be possible too.

Comment: *my data is stored deflated in a database*. So why not make that a zip file in the first place?

Comment: @g00se this is part of another framework which cannot be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.setMethod(STORED)` is like calling `zip -0`: It's telling the Zip library that you want the data to be stored uncompressed. It's not what you want.

The zip library is **not capable** of delivering on this.

There's a somewhat more expansive zip library out there that supports more of zip's features: [lingala-zip4j](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j).

I don't think that library can do the job either. So, if you want to do this, you'd have to fork it. At least you now have a thing to fork.

Assuming the data you have is compressed with DEFLATE, you can indeed do what you want - it's just a matter of writing the right zip header info. Forking lingala, or handwriting your own, given that the only thing you need it to do is emit zip files that most zip tools can read, is not actually all that complicated; the zip header structure is a bit weird but you just need enough to successfully compress your own data. Wikipedia for some reason has the [full breakdown of the zip format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) if you prefer to just write it from scratch instead of forking lingala.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to roll your own zip wrappers around the deflate data. The zip format is well documented in the [PKWare APPNOTE](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-6.3.9.TXT).

First, you need to make sure that it actually is raw deflate data. It might be a zlib stream, or possibly even a gzip stream. If so, you will first need to strip those wrappers to get the raw deflate data.

Then you will need to decompress the deflate data to get two pieces of information: the length of the uncomrpessed data, and the CRC-32 of the uncompressed data. Those will be required to fill in the zip headers.

With the raw deflate data, the uncompressed length, and the uncompressed CRC, it will be straightforward to create a single-entry zip file with that data. You will just need to make up a file name for the entry.